# How to add a group of columns and add a "+" button

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

I have a problem on adding a group of the same column name in the custom list. I need to add the button for user to add the same columns. If user click on the "+" button, the columns will displayed in the form with the same name.  Is it possible to do this? If yes, how can I solve this issue without using Sharepoint Designer?

For example, I want to add the 'Dependant Name', 'Age' and 'School/Institute' if user click on the + button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MS InfoPath to customize your form with Repeating table.

Reference:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-repeating-data-controls-2e9994d5-6cc9-4840-b23b-796f1ab9c58f
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-a-repeating-table-e313db25-fbd6-4dcd-b874-60c0b377c574

Comment: Is there any other solution that I can do? Because I don't have a permission to use the MS InfoPath.

Comment: You can insert Javascript to allow dynamic insert fields. Users will see multiple fields accordingly but at the backend the values are stored as "value1;value2;value3" etc. However, I fail to find a good sample online giving SP2010 is quite old.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a new form in the InfoPath, insert a repeating section in the form, then insert three text box in the repeating section.
[image]
2.Publish the form to SharePoint list.

3.Click Insert item, result as following picture shows.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your guide. But for now, I don't have a permission to use MS InfoPath.

Comment: You can ask administrator to create list form.